# Updating App Engine GWT web app - the correct way?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I have a website, completely written in GWT, using App Engine, and whenever I update the codebase I want users to use the latest version of my compiled GWT code. Problem is, users often see exceptions like the one below, until they refresh their page.

Am I handling updates in the right way:

- I update the version field in appengine-web.xml, deploy it, then make it active in App Engine.
- However, I found that sometimes users' browsers still end up using an old version
- To fix this, the first request I do to my server is to check a VERSION string, and if it is wrong then I manually do a Window.Location.reload()
- This works (most of the time)
- Problem is that sometimes on load I get exceptions like those shown at the bottom of this question.  When I refresh the page, everything works fine.

Main problem is that I have no way to reproduce it, and none of the code in the stack trace is mine.

Any suggestions on how to:

- reproduce it?
- debug it?
- prevent it?
- update my web app in the correct way?

Stack trace:

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: 3 exceptions caught: (Error) : Permission denied to access property 'target'; (Error) : Permission denied to access property 'target'; (Error) : Permission denied to access property 'target' 3 exceptions caught: (Error) : Permission denied to access property 'target'; (Error) : Permission denied to access property 'target'; (Error) : Permission denied to access property 'target'
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.StackTraceCreator$CollectorEmulated.$fillInStackTrace(StackTraceCreator.java:174)
    at java.lang.RuntimeException.RuntimeException(RuntimeException.java:508)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException.UmbrellaException(UmbrellaException.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException.UmbrellaException(UmbrellaException.java:26)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.$fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:90)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.Event$NativePreviewEvent.fire(Event.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.previewEvent(DOM.java:1328)
    at Unknown.anonymous(DOMImplStandard.java:152)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java:189)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Impl.java:70)
    at Unknown.anonymous(DOMImplStandard.java:187)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java:189)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Impl.java:70)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error) : Permission denied to access property 'target' (Error) : Permission denied to access property 'target'
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.StackTraceCreator$CollectorEmulated.$fillInStackTrace(StackTraceCreator.java:174)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException.JavaScriptException(JavaScriptException.java:508)
    at com.google.gwt.lang.Exceptions.caught(Exceptions.java:29)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel.$eventTargetsPopup(PopupPanel.java:1167)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel.$previewNativeEvent(PopupPanel.java:1340)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel$3.onPreviewNativeEvent(PopupPanel.java:1435)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.Event$NativePreviewEvent.dispatch(Event.java:194)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.$doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:194)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.$fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: For what it's worth, we have the exact same issue (same stack trace, etc.), but have not figured out the root problem.  Did you solve this?

Comment: hey @throp. Unfortunately not.  Do let me know if you find a solution.  I think it's to do with Same origin policy (e.g accessing a property coming from outer iframe), but I'm truly not sure.